# how do i write a truth table for ∀n ∈ N, P (n) → P (n + 1).?

Tags: logic

So i'm supposed to find a predicate such that: ∀n ∈ N, P (n) → P (n + 1) is true and write the truth table for it. So I chose the predicate: "11^n - 6 is divisible by 5 for every positive integer n". Since the truth table could go on forever, I was told to only do a few cases to get the idea.

I'm really stuck to be honest. I remember doing truth tables for predicates like "for all x in N, (P V Q). And that was easy to set the truth table up but It seems i need a value for my P now and I'm not too sure how to set this table up. Could someone point me towards the right direction?

I wrote down:

P: "11^n - 6 is divisible by 5 for every positive integer n"

```
P(1) | P(2) | P(1) -> P(2)
  T  |   T  |        T
```

This doesn't look right to me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote $T=1=\text{true}$ and $F=0=\text{false}$ (this is a more favourable notation when we've got loads of statements and it's hard to keep track of all the $T$s and $F$s, whereas we can count in binary with $1$s and $0s$).

Since there are two statements, $P(1)$ and $P(2),$ there are $2^2=4$ possibilities.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    P(1)&P(2)&P(1) \rightarrow P(2)\\  \hline
0&0&1\\  \hline
0&1&?\\  \hline
1&0&? \\ \hline
1&1&?\\ \hline\end{array}$$

Note that, by definition, $P(1) \to P(2)$ is false when $P(1)=1, P(2)=0$ and true otherwise.

Complete this truth table.

Comment: Is it 1, 0, 1??

Comment: user125535 Exactly! ${}{}{}{}$